# Associations in has_many , belong_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I am stuck at a small problem,but it has been so long for me trying to figure out what am i doing wrong. My scenario is i have a existing model `user` and now i create another model called `user_comment'. I have created below mentioned details:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user_comments
end
```

User_comment Model:

```
 class UserComment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    end
```

Migration File:

```
class CreateUserComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_comments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string  :comments
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After running `rake db:migrate` i went to `rails console` and then to setup the relation between two tables i did the following and nothing is working

```
obj1= User.first
```

I added first new row in user_comments table and then did ..

```
obj2= UserComment.first
```

Doing `obj1.obj2= obj2` is giving me

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `obj2=' for #<User:0x00000005f8e850>
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/insane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help me how to form an association ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does SmileComment suddenly come from?

Anyway, there are several things going wrong. First off, I would change the name of your model from UserComment to Comment. The fact that a comment belongs to an user is already made clear through your association. Calling User.first.user_comments seems a bit akward.

Let us start with a really basic example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

As you did in your migration, the comments needs a user_id to reference the user it belongs to. After running the migration, calling the association is dead simple:

```
User.first.comments # Gives all comments belonging to that user
```

Or:

```
Comment.first.user # Gives the user that belongs to that comment
```

Answer (score 2):

`obj1.obj2= obj2` is wrong, you need a space between `obj1.obj2` and `=`.

But `ob1.obj2` make no sense too(there is no `obj2` method in `User`).

Add an object to an association you could do:

```
user = User.first
comment = UserComment.first

# if both object are not nil, then you could do below
user.user_commentes << comment
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj1.obj2= obj2` => self-referential loop?

---

You'll be best reading the Rails [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide - you'll find what you're dealing with is actually relatively simple to remedy

As described by `@rails4guides.com`, you'll be best renaming your `UserComment` model to just `Comment` (as this will allow you to associate any data you need with it -- if you wanted to extend later):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This is actually down to [relational database naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), whereby each table's data can be associated with another's. They do this with `foreign_keys` - which is how Rails uses the associations defined in your models to create the likes of `@user.comments`:

```
class Comments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id => this is the foreign_key, which means Rails can append these objects to your `user` object
      t.string  :comments
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

So if you want to give the user a set of comments, you'll just need to call the `User` object from your model, and since Rails' ActiveRecord associations automatically call any relational data through your schemas, you'll get `comments` appended to the `@user` object with `@user.comments`